# How do I get a local git checkout to reflect precisely a known remote commit and nothing more?

Tags: git

What is a canonical sequence of git commands to get a local git checkout to precisely reflect the HEAD of a remote branch, with all files up-to-date, and nothing more in the checkout directory? Effectively I am trying to simulate having freshly cloned a repository, but without the network-intensiveness that might require.

My best approximation so far is:

```
cd <the git directory>
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -f -d -x
git fetch --prune
git checkout <the git branch name I want>
git pull --rebase
```

Are any of my steps unnecessary, or are there any I am missing?

(as an aside, the reason I want to do this is as part of an automated build system - I want to guarantee the build is working off a precise pristine copy, but cloning is very slow, so I'd like to just request fresh changes.

Comment: Have you tried `git archive`? It should also work with remotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need:

```
git fetch
git checkout <branch>
git reset --hard origin/<branch>
git clean -dxf
```

This represents:

- Syncing remote tracking branches with the remote
- Switch context to the branch you want.
- Reset that branch to the state on the remote repository.
- Remove any non source controlled files, including those that fall under the .gitignore

Pruning is mostly likely unnecessary, though it will protect you against setting yourself to a state that no longer exists on the remote. If that sounds useful, the fetch can be run with the `--prune` flag. A pull is unnecessary since you can reference the remote tracking branches directly using the `origin/{branch}` syntax.

**EDIT:**

If it's a possibility that `<branch>` has been modified inbetween runs of these commands, you may end up with changes in your working tree that prevent you from checking out the branch in step 2. If that happens, you can either `git stash` or `git reset --hard` to either save your changes or wipe them completely before checking out the branch.

Comment: However, if I had freshly cloned the repo (which is what I was comparing it to), my local branch would correspond to the same commit as <origin>/branch, wouldn't it? Therefore, I think perhaps I should do a pull for completeness?

Comment: The `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` command actually forces the state of your current branch (which we checked out in the line prior) to correspond to the same commit as <origin>/branch.
  
  Pull is just a combination of `fetch`, which we already did, and `merge` which will only do what you're expecting if the origin changes are a fast-forward change so I don't believe it's what you're looking for here.

Comment: joshtkling, fair point, I hadn't thought about it in those terms. OK, great, I think we have a good sequence of commands here. Thanks!

Comment: I subsequently found that I had to add an additional `git reset --hard HEAD` after the `git fetch` but before the `git checkout`, otherwise if I'd made (harmless, disposable) local file changes, git would refuse to do the checkout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer for anyone else who might stumble upon this post in search of a similar solution.

Comment: Please remove `git clean -dxf` line. I copied pasted thinking it is just cleaning some unnecessary files like cache, but it removed all the non git files.